# I Do not Understand What Is wrong with the following code

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
    savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
    String type = savedInstanceState.getString(TYPE);
    if(type == "tree")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound_tree);
    }
    else
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading_sound);
        tv.setText("'"+type+"'");
    }
```

I have used this code in the second activity. I know for sure that type == tree. So I do not understand why the first "if" block fails. It always goes to the "else" block, even though I am 100% sure that type == "tree". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never compare string values with the `==` operator. Use the `equals` method instead.

The `==` operator compares object by references, not by values.

Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Fixed code:

```
savedInstanceState = getIntent().getExtras();
String type = savedInstanceState.getString(TYPE);
if(type.equals("tree"))
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound_tree);
}
else
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading_sound);
    tv.setText("'"+type+"'");
}
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but `equals`.

Comment: @Chris You should be picky.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [classic String comparison question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530864/java-why-doesnt-my-string-comparison-work), try

```
"tree".equals(type); // This is also safe from NullPointerException since you are comparing type with a constant 'tree', which is not null
```

**Why Equals?**

A detailed explanation regarding using `==` vs `equals()` can be found [here](http://javacampus.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-string-comparison-works-in-java.html)

Comment: Oh Wow! That was the right answer. Could you explain why the "==" did not work?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
type.equals("tree")
```

instead of

```
type == "tree"
```

**Reason**

equls method check the values of the object where  == operator check whether they are the same instance of object.