# Java: Why can String equality be proven with ==?

Tags: java, string

I learned that it is from the devil to test String equality with `==` instead of `String.equals()`, because every String was a reference to its own object.

But if i use something like

```
System.out.println("Hello" == "Hello");
```

it prints true.

Why?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern. They also discuss this issue.

Comment: Please post an example that shows how "this works now".

Comment: How funny this came up - I was reversing {string == null ? "" : string} - all my tests passed, but when strings started being read from the database...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't. It's still a bad thing to do - you'll still be testing reference equality instead of value equality.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x = "hello";
        String y = new String(x);
        System.out.println(x == y); // Prints false
    }
}
```

If you're seeing == testing "work" now then it's because you genuinely have equal references. The most common reason for seeing this would probably be due to interning of String literals, but that's been in Java forever:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x = "hello";
        String y = "hel" + "lo"; // Concatenated at compile-time
        System.out.println(x == y); // Prints true
    }
}
```

This is guaranteed by [section 3.10.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5) of the Java Language Specification:

> Each string literal is a reference
>   (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1, §12.5)
>   of class String (§4.3.3). String
>   objects have a constant value. String
>   literals-or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant
>   expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so
>   as to share unique instances, using
>   the method String.intern.

Comment: Thank you - but why is it working if i use two identical literals?

Answer (score 3):

It hasn't changed. However, the Java Compiler uses string.intern() to make sure that identical strings in source code compile to same String object. If however you load a String from a File or Database it will not be the same object, unless you force this using String.intern() or some other method.

It is a bad idea, and you should still use .equals()

Comment: Manually interning String objects is risky because they can never be un-interned or garbage collected. One could easily consume all of the available memory that way.

Comment: @Adriaan - unreachable interned Strings are garbage collected.  This was apparently implemented in JDK 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Look, this is a tricky concept.

There is a difference between:

```
// These are String literals
String a = "Hiabc";
String b = "abc";
String c = "abc";
```

and

```
// These are String objects.
String a = new String("Hiabc");
String b = new String("abc");
String c = new String("abc");
```

If your strings were objects, i.e.,

```
String b = new String("abc");
String c = new String("abc");
```

Then, two different objects would have been created in the String pool at two different memory locations and doing

```
b == c
```

would have resulted `false`.

But since your `String b` and `String c` are literals,

```
b == c
```

results `true`. This is because two different objects were not created. And both `a` and `b` are pointing to same String in the stack memory.

This is the difference. You are right, `==` compares for memory location. And that is the reason,

```
a.substring(2, 5) == b; // a,substring(2, 5) = "abc" which is at the location of b, and
b == c // will be true, coz both b and c are literals. And their values are compared and not memory locations.
```

In order to have two separate Strings with same values but at different locations in the `String pool` and **NOT** `stack memory`, you need to create String objects as shown above.

So,

```
a.substring(2, 5) == b; // and
b == c; // will be false. as not both are objects. Hence are stored on separate memory locations on the String pool.
```

you have to use

```
a.substring(2, 5).equals(b);
b.equals(c);
```

in case of objects.