# Unexpected Boolean Result

Tags: java

I have the following Java code:

```
String p = "seven";
String q = "teen";
p + q == "seventeen";
```

Why does the last line return `false` and not `true`?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858569/java-why-can-string-equality-be-proven-with

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you should use the [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for `String` comparison. The `==` operator compares the object references, and those are unique for each object. You would only get `true` for a `==` comparison when comparing an object to itself.

Try `(p + q).equals("seventeen");`

Note, that `String`comparison in java is case-sensitive, so you might also want to take a look at the [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 4):

(p + q).intern() == "seventeen"

**intern** will return the string from the pool

Answer (score 0):

When comparing `Strings`, you must use the `String` method `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`, otherwise you are comparing objects.  since `p` + `q` is a different object than `"seventeen"`, your result will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Because == is reference equality and not logical equality.  Strings are immutable so you are getting new Strings, which won't be the same location in memory.  Try:

```
String p = "seven";
String q = "teen";
(p + q).equals("seventeen");
```