# String literal memory utilization

Tags: java, string, memory

In java there is concept of string literal pool. If I am not creating any string in my code, this memory pool is waste for me. How can I use this memory area instead of keeping it for string literal pool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we avoid interning of strings in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672688/can-we-avoid-interning-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "string literal pool"; string literals are [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), but that means they are just normal objects on the heap. They presumably get referenced a lot and in this way save on memory, but fundamentally they are no different than any other object.

If no string literals exist in your program (and you don't ever call [`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)) then the JVM does not allocate heap memory for such. There is no "hidden" memory area involved, and you don't need to do anything to "get access to it".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes any sense. Anyway, theoretically, string pool is in permgen area of Java heap. This is the same memory where JVM stores classes. By default (at least for Oracle HotSpot JVM) it is 64 M. You can try to configure this area with two HotSpot JVM options: -XX:MaxPermSize and -XX:PermSize. The less permgen the more memory for objects.

Comment: +1 Note: strings are on the heap (outisde perm gen) since Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use this memory area instead of keeping it for string literal pool.

It is the area reserved by JVM and being increased (upto some threshold) as program runs. In short, you can't use it for some other purpose.

Comment: Are you saying that the pool has a fixed reserved space, whether it uses it or not?

Comment: Nope!! If not used at all, it'll be empty. (i.e. heap)