# java: readLine method put string into string literal pool?

Tags: java

I know that String a = "hello"; will put the "hello" into string literal pool. my question is:
1.

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hell"+"o";
```

Does the string literal pool has three object: "hello", "hell", and "o"?

2.

```
String a = "hello";
String b = new String("hello");
```

then there will be a "hello" object in string literal pool and a string object in heap?

3.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names"));
String line = br.readLine(); //(the value of line is "hello" now, for example)
```

then there will be a "hello" object in string literal pool and a string object in heap?

Comment: Just a comment for part 1, the compiler may optimise the second one into just `String b = "hello";`, so no guarantees there.

Comment: @appclay The compiler is *required* to intern strings that are the values of constant-expressions, by http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5. This is a guarantee.

Comment: @EJP Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIk, these are the things happening:

1.when javac compiler encounters the above line, it will change it to `StringBuffer` like this:

```
String b = new StringBuffer().append("hell").append("o").toString();

String a will be in pool with the value "hello".
```

2 `String b will in the heap`.

3.This is purely an in memory operation as it is loading the file contents dynamically.Java compiler never

get a chance to know its memory structure because it is depending on the file size now.So it cannot be pooled.But when you perform a intern() these are the things happening:

If you call a string with method intern(), it is definitely garbage collected in modern  JVMS.
   It can be used to save memory if many string with the same content.

There is a nice discussion about this here:

[Is it good practice to use java.lang.String.intern()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern)

Comment: for question 1, I don't understand why b is created by new stringBuffer. because if System.out.println(a==b), the result is true. So I think a and b refer to the same object "hello" in the pool. but if b is created by new stringBuffer, "hello" object will in the heap.

Comment: this is how internally the java compiler retains the string,for more information you can visit this link.http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPMutability.fm.html#22028

Answer (score 4):

3) `readLine()` won't use the value from the string pool.  You would have to call [`intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) on it first.

```
line = br.readLine().intern();
```

From the [`String` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29):

> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in [§3.10.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/html/).