# What is wrong with comparing these two elements from a string array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison

Java newbie and I'm stuck on something that seems really simple.  I wrote an algorithm for a game I'm building and, using TDD, all of my tests pass, but the actual game is not returning the right feedback.    Instead, whenever I guess a correct letter, it returns a "w" and should return a "b".

**Background**
The game starts by generating a 4 character random code.  The objective of the game is to enter a guess and try to match the secret code.  The feedback class is supposed to tell me if my guess is hot or cold compared to the code.

I pass the guess and secret code to the class and calculate the feedback.  The guess is a string that I use "split" to turn into a String array.  The secret code is also a string Array that I randomly generate 4 different string values for.  I tried checking to see if one element from both the guess and secret code are strings and got "true" on both.

**Problem**
Problem is that my exact matches if statement never gets executed.  I read that you should use equals() instead and also tried that but get an error.

Can anyone help?

Here is my Feedback class:
        public class Feedback {

```
      public String[] guess;
      public String[] secretCode;
      public String[] feedback;

      public String[] get(String[] guess, String[] secretCode) {
        this.guess = Arrays.copyOf(guess, guess.length);
        this.secretCode = Arrays.copyOf(secretCode, secretCode.length);
        feedback = new String[this.secretCode.length];
        findExactMatches();
        findNearMatches();
        findNoMatches();
        sortFeedback();
        return feedback;
      }

      public void findExactMatches() {
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
          if (guess[i] == secretCode[i]) {
            feedback[i] = "b";
            guess[i] = "x";
            secretCode[i] = "x";
          }
        }
      }

      public void findNearMatches() {
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
          if ( Arrays.asList(secretCode).contains(guess[i]) && guess[i] != "x" ) {
            feedback[i] = "w";
            int matched_symbol_index = Arrays.asList(secretCode).indexOf(guess[i]);
            secretCode[matched_symbol_index] = "x";
          }
        }
      }

      public void findNoMatches() {
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
          if ( feedback[i] == null ) {
            feedback[i] = " ";
          }
        }
      }

      public void sortFeedback() {
        Arrays.sort(feedback);
      }
    }
```

Comment: *"I read that you should use equals() instead and also tried that but get an error."*.  It would help if you told us what that error was, because FIXING it is probably the only real solution.

Comment: -1; question's been asked and answered half a billion times already here and elsewhere on Google.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid the repeated call to Arrays.asList() inside the for loops. Either go with raw arrays and write you own contains() and indexOf() methods; or stick with some ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you Gyro!  That was a helpful tip.  I took your advice and rolled my own method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing `String`s, use `equals` instead of `==`. `String.equals` will compare the content, while `==` will compare the identity (that is if they are the same object or not).

So,

```
guess[i] == secretCode[i]
```

should be

```
guess[i].equals(secretCode[i])
```

If you want to learn more, then you could do `==` if you **[interned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern)** the string. But that's completely bonus content.

Edit: And also, as johnchen902 said in the comment:

> And guess[i] != "x" should be !guess[i].equals("x"). (in findNearMatches())

Comment: And `guess[i] != "x"` should be `!guess[i].equals("x")`. (in `findNearMatches()`)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had read about "equals" several times, but I guess I read it wrong.  I was trying to do equals(guess[i], secretCode[i]) instead of the way you described.

Answer (score 3):

These are `strings` so you should use `equals`, i.e. `guess[i].equals(secretCode[i])`

`guess[i] == secretCode[i]` will compare reference of the two string ("`operator compares the objects’ location(s) in memory"`) which you do not want.

Please look at this for more -- http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

And same applies for `guess[i] != "x"`  so you will use `! guess[i].equals("x")`

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `guess[i] == secretCode[i]` with `guess[i].equals(secretCode[i])` and the `guess[i] != "x"` with `!guess[i].equals("x")` .

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

You can find more info [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

```
public String[] guess;
      public String[] secretCode;
      public String[] feedback;

      public String[] get(String[] guess, String[] secretCode) {
        this.guess = Arrays.copyOf(guess, guess.length);
        this.secretCode = Arrays.copyOf(secretCode, secretCode.length);
        feedback = new String[this.secretCode.length];
        findExactMatches();
        findNearMatches();
        findNoMatches();
        sortFeedback();
        return feedback;
      }

      public void findExactMatches() {
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
          if (guess[i].equals(secretCode[i]) ) {
            feedback[i] = "b";
            guess[i] = "x";
            secretCode[i] = "x";
          }
        }
      }

      public void findNearMatches() {
        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length; i++) {
          if ( Arrays.asList(secretCode).contains(guess[i]) && !guess[i].equals("x") ) {
            feedback[i] = "w";
            int matched_symbol_index = Arrays.asList(secretCode).indexOf(guess[i]);
            secretCode[matched_symbol_index] = "x";
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I see what I was doing wrong now.  And thanks so much for the description of how the two methods compare and the link.