# String.intern() how exactly work

Tags: java, string, char

I am wondering why in the following code:

```
   String args0 = args[0];
   String args1 = args[1];
   args0.intern();
   args1.intern();

   if (args0==args1){
      System.out.println("Success");
   } else {
      System.out.println("Failure");
   }
```

by passing as a line command argument 2 identical strings it gives back `failure`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Being `String` inmutable, wouldn't you need to assign the instance `intern()` returns in order to reference the interned instance ? `args0` and `args1` are still the original distinct instances in the array.

Comment: Useful info about String.intern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern

Comment: @XaviLópez yep you right, forgot to type it. Correcting it now

Comment: Ok it works. my bad closing the question.

Comment: @Rollerball Your edit is not helpful because the code works but your question says it does not.

Comment: @assylias you right. changed in as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do:

```
if (args0.intern() == args1.intern()){
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Being `String` inmutable, you'd need to assign the instance `intern()` returns in order to make the variables reference the interned instance, so that the `==` comparison would return `true`.

```
String args0 = args[0];
String args1 = args[1];
args0 = args0.intern();
args1 = args1.intern();

if (args0==args1){
   System.out.println("Success");
} else {
   System.out.println("Failure");
}
```

In your example `args0` and `args1` are still referencing the original distinct instances in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are **immutable**.

`.intern()` returns a (potentially) *different* String instance that is in the intern pool.

You're throwing this instance away.

Answer (score 0):

Java automatically interns String literals. This means that in many cases, the == operator appears to work for Strings in the same way that it does for ints or other primitive values.

Since interning is automatic for String literals, the `intern()` method is to be used on Strings constructed with `new String()`.

You can refer this example also:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str1 = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
      String Str2 = new String("WELCOME TO SUTORIALSPOINT.COM");

      System.out.print("Canonical representation:" );
      System.out.println(Str1.intern());

      System.out.print("Canonical representation:" );
      System.out.println(Str2.intern());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that `args0` and `args1` holds Strings with same value)

1. `args0.intern()` will check if String pool already contains String with same value as String from `args0`.
2. If pool contains such String reference to it will be returned, if not new String with same value as `args0` will be created, placed in pool reference to it returned.

after

```
args0.intern();
args1.intern();
```

`args0` and `args1` still hold Strings used in command line so they are different from Strings in pool.

To change it try maybe

```
args0 = args0.intern();
args1 = args1.intern();
```

now `args0 = args0.intern();` will place "put" String from `args0` in pool update `args0` to hold that String. After `args1 = args1.intern();` intern will see that pool contains same string (placed earlier with `args0.intern()`) so will just return reference to it and store it under `args1`.

Now `if(args0 == args1)` should be `true` because both references hods the same String object.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable and its methods always return the altered `String`:

```
 args0 = args0.intern();
 args1 = args1.intern();
```