# Purpose of String.intern() in java

Tags: java

Anyone Know purpose of String.intern()  using java programming...

If i use intern what is the difference between ordinary string and string.intern()

Comment: This is a great thread explaining the same:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-constants

Comment: See [`String#intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)

Comment: Please refer this link. You can get good idea

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern

Comment: even this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-constants)

Comment: There are two suggestions to close this question as of now, but both suggestions state that it is a duplicate of questions that refer to using intern on string literals.  This is a broader question, not a duplicate of these.

Answer (score 1):

[string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is a method of storing only one copy of each distinct string value, which must be immutable. Interning strings makes some string processing tasks more time- or space-efficient at the cost of requiring more time when the string is created or interned. The distinct values are stored in a string intern pool.

Also read [String pooling](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Interned String are stored in String pool rather than on general heap space. Prior to Java 7 this pool was in permgen area but from java 7 it has been moved to heap to prevent `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error which leds to JVM crash.

To summarize interned string with same text(.equals() returns true) will point to same object in string pool i.e even == operation will give true. Normal Strings created with new() with same content(.equals() returns true) will give false to == operation as they point to two different objects.

You may want to go through a good article  [Busting java.lang.String.intern() Myths](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html) . I am sure it will clear most of your doubts(Article also contains Java examples you can execute to see the results yourself).