# Regarding intern() method in String

Tags: java, string

```
String s1=new String("Raam");
String s2=s1.concat("Kumar");
String s3=s2.intern();
String s4="RaamKumar";
System.out.println("s3==s4..."+(s3==s4)); //true
```

`intern()` method checks whether particular object exiting in  String Constant pool or not . Oterwise it will create that object in String Constant pool. But What is the need of String `intern()`.which scenario it is useful?

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern

Comment: What's gonna happen if you don't do the `s2.intern()` doesn't it automatically get interned?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo Interning is only done automatically for string literals present in the source code

Answer (score 0):

It is almost never useful. As per `String` class documentation, `String` literals are always interned. That is, if I say

```
String a = "A String";
String b = "A String";
```

, a single object will be put on the heap and both `a` and `b` will point to the same reference.

So, I would say this is syntactic sugar that makes any call to `intern()` unneeded.

Comment: The question concerned when it was useful not when it wasn't.