# How does String.intern() work and how does it affect the String pool?

Tags: java, string

As we know, `String().intern()` method add String value in string pool if it's not already exist. If exists, it returns the reference of that value/object.

```
String str = "Cat"; // creates new object in string pool  with same character sequence.  
String st1 = "Cat"; // has same reference of object in pool, just created in case of 'str'

 str == str1 //that's returns true

String test = new String("dog");
test.intern();// what this line of code do behind the scene
```

I need to know, when i call `test.intern()` what this intern method will do?

add "dog" with different reference in string pool or add `test` object reference in string pool(i think, it's not the case )?

I tried this

```
String test1 = "dog";

test == test1 // returns false
```

I just want to make sure, when I call `test.intern()` it creates new object with same value in String pool? now I have 2 objects with value "dog". one exist directly in heap and other is in String pool?

Comment: `str == str //that's returns true` typo?

Comment: sorry it shouldbe str == str1. let me edit my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it good practice to use java.lang.String.intern()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern)

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc?

Comment: You should use the `.equals()` method to compare strings, not `==`

Comment: i'm not asking about value comparision.

Comment: @RahulTripathi i'm asking something else. read-up again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> when i call `test.intern()` what this intern method will do?

It will put the `"dog"` string in the string pool (unless it's already there). But it will not necessarily put *the object* that `test` refers to in the pool. This is why you typically do

```
test = test.intern();
```

Note that if you have a `"dog"` literal in your code, then there will already be a `"dog"` in the string pool, so `test.intern()` will return that object.

Perhaps your experiment confuses you, and it was in fact the following experiment you had in mind:

```
String s1 = "dog";             // "dog" object from string pool
String s2 = new String("dog"); // new "dog" object on heap

System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // false

s2 = s2.intern();              // intern() returns the object from string pool

System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // true
```

Comment: So, now s2 pointing to an object exist in pool but not the object in heap? right ? 

BTW Thanks. I got my answer.

Comment: Yes. You're right. `s2.intern()` will return an object from the pool, so before `s2 = s2.intern()` the `s2` variable will point at an object on the heap, and afterwards it will point at an object from the pool.