# Java equals primitive vs object speed

Tags: java, performance, equals

Just tried to test speed of equals when using Objects.equals vs Primitive comparison. If somebody needs the code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.TimeValue;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class BaseEquals {
    byte bytePrim;
    short shortPrim;
    int intPrim;
    long longPrim;
    float floatPrim;
    double doublePrim;
    boolean booleanPrim;
    char charPrim;

    BaseEquals() {
        bytePrim = 1;
        shortPrim = 1;
        intPrim = 1;
        longPrim = 1;
        floatPrim = 1.0f;
        doublePrim = 1.0d;
        booleanPrim = true;
        charPrim = '1';
    }
}

class EqualsObjects extends BaseEquals {

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bytePrim,
                shortPrim,
                intPrim,
                longPrim,
                floatPrim,
                doublePrim,
                booleanPrim,
                charPrim);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof EqualsObjects)) {
            return false;
        }
        EqualsObjects eo = (EqualsObjects)obj;
        return Objects.equals(bytePrim, eo.bytePrim)
                && Objects.equals(shortPrim, eo.shortPrim)
                && Objects.equals(intPrim, eo.intPrim)
                && Objects.equals(longPrim, eo.longPrim)
                && Objects.equals(floatPrim, eo.floatPrim)
                && Objects.equals(doublePrim, eo.doublePrim)
                && Objects.equals(booleanPrim, eo.booleanPrim)
                && Objects.equals(charPrim, eo.charPrim);
    }
}

class EqualsPrimitives extends BaseEquals {

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bytePrim,
                shortPrim,
                intPrim,
                longPrim,
                floatPrim,
                doublePrim,
                booleanPrim,
                charPrim);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof EqualsPrimitives)) {
            return false;
        }
        EqualsPrimitives eo = (EqualsPrimitives)obj;
        return bytePrim == eo.bytePrim
                && shortPrim == eo.shortPrim
                && intPrim == eo.intPrim
                && longPrim == eo.longPrim
                && Float.compare(floatPrim, eo.floatPrim) == 0
                && Double.compare(doublePrim, eo.doublePrim) == 0
                && booleanPrim == eo.booleanPrim
                && charPrim == eo.charPrim;
    }
}

public class EqualsTests {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class MyState {
        EqualsObjects eo1;
        EqualsObjects eo2;
        EqualsPrimitives ep1;
        EqualsPrimitives ep2;

        @Setup
        public void setup() throws Throwable {
            eo1 = new EqualsObjects();
            eo2 = new EqualsObjects();
            ep1 = new EqualsPrimitives();
            ep2 = new EqualsPrimitives();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void equalsObject(MyState state) throws Throwable {
        boolean b1 = state.eo1.equals(state.eo2);
        boolean b2 = state.eo2.equals(state.eo1);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void equalsPrimitive(MyState state) throws Throwable {
        boolean b1 = state.ep1.equals(state.ep2);
        boolean b2 = state.ep2.equals(state.ep1);
    }

    @Test
    public void launch() throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(this.getClass().getName() + ".*")
                .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
                .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
                .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
                .warmupIterations(5)
                .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(5))
                .measurementIterations(10)
                .threads(2)
                .forks(1)
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .shouldDoGC(true)
                .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }
}
```

What I saw in the end is this results:

```
Benchmark                    Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
EqualsTests.equalsObject     avgt   10  0.026 ±  0.001  us/op
EqualsTests.equalsPrimitive  avgt   10  0.011 ±  0.001  us/op
```

Do you think it is worth using primitive comparison to have faster equals methods (probably neglectable to other operations in code), or using Objects.equals to have unified code (not to think about using Double.compare and Float.compare for double and float primitives respectively, and == for other primitives) in equals method?

Comment: Please, remove the horizontal scollbar.

Comment: What is 15% faster? Primitive `==` compared to `Object.equals`, or the entirety of the complex `equals` method, including all those calls to `Arrays.equals`?

Comment: Complete function execution. But since both are equal, I think that you can  say also that it is == compared to Object.equals.

Comment: If you say that, you are being deceptive.  That is, the *absolute* difference in runtime is attributable mostly or wholly to the difference between `==` and (autoboxing + `equals()`), but the 15% *relative* difference you actually report is skewed by the inclusion of all the array comparisons in both your tests.  If you take out the duplicate code then the relative difference cannot help but increase, probably by a lot.

Comment: In any event, it's unclear to me what you mean by "hav[ing] unified code in equals method".  Since that seems to define an important part of the scope of your question, you would do well to clarify, ideally with the help of some example code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, 15% was relative in this case. Anyway, there is speed difference between this 2 examples (I suppose absolute diff in time needed to box/unbox). Unified code - means instead of thinking about using Double.compare and Float.compare and == for other primitives we always use Objects.equals. Again, this question was just to hear other opinions.

Comment: I was considering whether to VTC as primarily opinion-based; I guess "the question was just to hear other opinions" seals it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between both codes can be seen within their bytecode outputs.

Primitive value comparison is simply done with a single `if_icmpne` instruction, and thats it.

See, Instructions for `bytePrim == eo.bytePrim`

```
20: astore_2
21: aload_0
22: getfield      #3                  // Field bytePrim:B
25: aload_2
26: getfield      #3                  // Field bytePrim:B
29: if_icmpne     246
```

On the otherhand, Object comparision (`Object.equals`) requires primitives to be boxed to their Object equivalents (i.e. int to Integer, byte to Byte, char to Character etc.) before the comparison happens. Once both primitives are boxed, additional `invokestatic` instruction (Objects.equals) is invoked for completing the comparison (which internally does the primitive comparison with null checking etc.)

Instructions for `Objects.equals(bytePrim, eo.bytePrim)`

```
21: aload_0
22: getfield      #3                  // Field bytePrim:B
25: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Byte.valueOf:(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;
28: aload_2
29: getfield      #3                  // Field bytePrim:B
32: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Byte.valueOf:(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;
35: invokestatic  #30                 // Method java/util/Objects.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
38: ifeq
```

Answer (score 0):

Using wrappers instead of primitives should always have a reason. Basically, you should use primitive, but sometimes you need a wrapper.

The difference is that wrappers can be `null` and primitive is always set to it's initial value. This means, that when you want to have your own initial states or you want to know if the received `int` was 0 or wasn't present you'll definitely use wrapper.

There is no surprise that comparing primitives is faster than comparing wrappers. Calling `equals` costs as calling any other method costs. Anyway, your test should also compare what is the difference when comparing huge numbers. Now, we can only say, that comparing primitive ones is faster than comparing wrapped ones.

Look `Integer` caches numbers from -128 to 127. This changes a lot.

Comment: well, the reason for using wrappers here is to have more unified code and not to worry that you should use Double.compare instead of == etc... but on the other hand it is faster... This was not question, more to check other opinions is it more important for you to have clear code or speed

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `equals` method, because '==' checks value equality between primitive types or equal object identity (i.e. whether the operands are the same instance, not just logically equal).

This all evaluates to true:

```
42 == 42 // primitive values
int i = 42, j = 42; i == j // primitive values
Integer i = new Integer(42); i == 42 // auto-unboxing
Integer i = 42, j = 42; i == j // cached interned Integer instance
```

Yet this evaluates to false, contrary to what you might expect:

```
Integer i = new Integer(42); Integer j = new Integer(42); i == j // not cached, different objects
Integer i = new Integer("42"); Integer j = new Integer("42"); i == j
```

Only use `==` if you're comparing primitive types or wish to actually check reference equality to see if both operands are the same instance. Even for a primitive type as one operand and a wrapper type as the other it's best not to, because the auto-unboxing can lead to nullpointer exceptions if the wrapper variable is null. It can be argued that `==` is also okay to use for enum constants, but that tends to lead to... debates.