# Java char array to String without creating new objects

Tags: java, jvm, string-pool

When creating a String like this:

```
String s1 = “ABC”
```

the JVM will look in the String pool if "ABC" exists there and create a new object only if "ABC" doesn't exist yet.

So the usage of

```
String s1 = new String("ABC")
```

halts this behavior and will create an object every time.

Now I have a problem when converting a char array to String:

```
private char[] names;
...
@Override
public String toString() {
  return new String(this.names);
}
```

This will always create a new object. Can I convert from char array to String without creating a new object each time?

Comment: What's your objective? Reduce memory usage, or avoid creating strings/garbage?

Comment: The objective is to reduce memory usage.

Comment: If memory is a real concern (e.g. if these are long-living strings), then consider switching on `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` (IIRC, this requires using G1GC).

Comment: That depends on why you use a `char[]` array in your class instead of just a reusable `String` reference.

Answer (score 2):

I know of no way to avoid creating a `String` object in your `toString()`, but you can avoid retaining these new strings (all but the first one become eligible for GC after the method execution) by explicitly calling `String.intern()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new String(this.names).intern();
}
```

And you can test it by repeatedly checking `myObject.toString() == myObject.toString()`.

But before doing this, do yourself a favor and [be aware of what you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern). It's possible that generating a string object is the better choice, depending on your main reason for doing this.